# php about arrays to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In php ,I have a array like this:

```
[
    [0] =>
        [
            [0] => 255
            [1] => 216
            [2] => 255
        ]
    [1] =>
        [
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 54
            [2] => 25455
        ]
]
```

And now I want array like that:

```
[
    [0] => 255
    [1] => 216
    [2] => 255
]
[
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 54
    [2] => 25455
]
```

any good ideas? in php language!

Comment: How would you plan to address items in such an array?

Comment: do you want to make an array of arrays a single array ?

Comment: What is the difference between 2 arrays?

Comment: so you want to split first array to two seperate array? because if you want expected outcome as a single array, then both input and expected outcome is identical(no difference)

Comment: Your both arrays are same.. Difference is just you entered manually.. Coding point of view both arrays are same.

Comment: Split them in 2 different arrays

Comment: @MoragHughson l want to pass reference to java of byte[] type ,but php not have a byte[] type ,so i am in trouble. Do u have any  good suggestion？

Comment: What is requirement to achieve this, if its 1 resultant array?

Comment: @rahulsm
The final need to turn the array into json

Comment: Once check my answer. I hope that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
<?php
        $arr = [
    0 =>
        [
            0 => 255,
            1 => 216,
            2 => 255,
        ],
    1 =>
        [
            0 => 25,
            1 => 54,
            2 => 25455,
        ]
];

echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Output**

```
[[255,216,255],[25,54,25455]]
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f21ab2700fa3c1537c7cedadda361cf96e2dffc0),

**json_encode** — Returns the JSON representation of a value